# Disk partion problems while installing ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I have quite problem with disk partions while installing ubuntu basically I am confused how to recognize the **C:** disk in ubuntu as windows showing it 68gb and when i see in ubuntu while installing it doesn't show any such thing i know it come in mb but no similar came pls help I have 2 hard drives and have important data in those so can't just wipe out all howvee i wanna fresh install ubuntu

Comment: I am free to answer any of your query in comment just help 

Comment: Two things. 1. There is no such thing as a C drive in Ubuntu that is a Windows term. 2. Your question is very hard to understand and you have failed to even say what version of Ubuntu you are trying to install.

Comment: Backup your important data: Mucking about with partitions and installing an Operating System are both inherently risky. Edit your question to show `parted` or `gparted` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to Linux!

All Unix based Operating systems (like Ubuntu) use a different File and Disk Layout than what Windows uses. Under Linux, you don't have drive Letters like C:, D:, etc. but instead there's a Filesystem root (displayed as "/") and all other Devices are just a File (e.g. /dev/sda1) that can be mounted to a Directory.

I know it's a bit confusing for Windows users, but basically, it means that in this case you will have to orientate yourself by the size of the Disk.

If you would like to learn more about this, there's a great Video from thiojoe about this topic: https://youtu.be/zZV4jSeBvFs

It talks a lot about why there typically is no A: or B: Drive in Windows, but at 3:12 he also explains how Linux handles Drives.

Comment: This might help today but what about later when this link is invalid?

Comment: It's not a Youtube watch link, but a Youtube share link, wich doesn't get invalid after 24 hours. You can get it by clicking "share" and "copy link" on a Videos page.

Comment: Years from now the link will still be valid?

Comment: I think so. I mean, now it's the next day and it still works, so why should it stop working? But i'm not 100% sure